# Gradients are zero in manual weights update in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to implement a simple neural net with manual update of weights for MNIST with AUTOGRAD, similar to AUTOGRAD example given [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html). This is my code:

```
import os
import sys

import torch
import torchvision
class Datasets:
    """Helper for extracting datasets."""

    def __init__(self, root='data/', batch_size=25):
        if not os.path.exists(root):
            os.mkdir(root)
        self.root = root
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def get_mnist_loaders(self):
        train_data = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
                root=self.root, train=True, download=True)
        test_data = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
                root=self.root, train=False, download=True)


        train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
                dataset=train_data, batch_size=self.batch_size, shuffle=True)
        test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
                dataset=test_data, batch_size=self.batch_size, shuffle=False)

        return train_loader, test_loader

    def create_batches(self, data, labels, batch_size):
        return [(data[i:i+batch_size], labels[i:i+batch_size])
            for i in range(0, len(data), max(1, batch_size))]

def train1():
    dtype = torch.float
    n_inputs = 28*28
    n_hidden1 = 300
    n_hidden2 = 100
    n_outputs = 10
    batch_size = 200
    n_epochs = 25
    learning_rate = 0.01
    test_step = 100 
    device = torch.device("cpu")

    datasets = Datasets(batch_size=batch_size)
    train_loader, test_loader = datasets.get_mnist_loaders()

    def feed_forward(X):
        x_shape = list(X.size())
        X = X.view(x_shape[0], x_shape[1]*x_shape[2])
        hidden1 = torch.mm(X, w1)
        hidden1 += b1
        hidden1 = hidden1.clamp(min=0)
        hidden2 = torch.mm(hidden1, w2) + b2
        hidden2 = hidden2.clamp(min=0)
        logits = torch.mm(hidden2, w3) + b3
        softmax = pytorch_softmax(logits)
        return softmax

    def accuracy(y_pred, y):

        if list(y_pred.size()) != list(y.size()):
            raise ValueError('Inputs have different shapes.')

        total_correct = 0
        total = 0
        for i, (y1, y2) in enumerate(zip(y_pred, y)):
            if y1 == y2:
                total_correct += 1
            total += 1

        return total_correct / total

    w1 = torch.randn(n_inputs, n_hidden1, device=device, dtype=dtype, requires_grad=True)
    b1 = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(n_hidden1), requires_grad=True)

    w2 = torch.randn(n_hidden1, n_hidden2, requires_grad=True)
    b2 = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(n_hidden2), requires_grad=True)

    w3 = torch.randn(n_hidden2, n_outputs, dtype=dtype, requires_grad=True)
    b3 = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(n_outputs), requires_grad=True)

    pytorch_softmax = torch.nn.Softmax(0)
    pytorch_cross_entropy = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='elementwise_mean')

    step = 0
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        batches = datasets.create_batches(train_loader.dataset.train_data,
                                          train_loader.dataset.train_labels,
                                          batch_size)
        for x, y in batches:
            step += 1

            softmax = feed_forward(x.float())
            vals, y_pred = torch.max(softmax, 1)
            accuracy_ = accuracy(y_pred, y)
            cross_entropy = pytorch_cross_entropy(softmax, y)

            print(epoch, step, cross_entropy.item(), accuracy_)

            cross_entropy.backward()

            with torch.no_grad():
                w1 -= learning_rate * w1.grad
                w2 -= learning_rate * w2.grad
                w3 -= learning_rate * w3.grad

                b1 -= learning_rate * b1.grad
                b2 -= learning_rate * b2.grad
                b3 -= learning_rate * b3.grad

                w1.grad.zero_()
                w2.grad.zero_()
                w3.grad.zero_()

                b1.grad.zero_()
                b2.grad.zero_()
                b3.grad.zero_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train1()
```

However the network doesn't seem to train. When I print parts of gradients (e.g. `w1.grad.data[:10, :10]`) they consist of zeros. I've tried to use `weight.data` and `weight.grad.data` to update the weights and tried to remove the `w.grad.zero_()` part (even though it is in the example) but it doesn't help. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

When you feed the network with Tensor, gradients are not calculating by default. To make it works you may wrap your FloatTensor into `torch.autograd.Variable` or set property `requires_grad` of tensor. [Here is an example.](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/examples_autograd/two_layer_net_autograd.html)

Comment: You set `requires_grad` for parameters, but not for the input tensor.

Comment: Why should I calculate gradients with respect to the inputs? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: If your inputs don't have gradients, all sequence of operations don't have gradients also (afaik, it's related to autograd).

Comment: In my code, using `x = x.float(); x.required_grad = True` doesn't help. The grads are still zeros. `y` should be `LongTensor` so it's impossible to set `require_grad` to `True` for `y`...

Comment: The example you have provided is the same one that I've posted. In this example, input tensors aren't set to autograd. Where did you take it?

Comment: I see. By the way, you don't have gradients, because you try to access it in the `with torch.no_grad():` block.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 issues here.

Firstly, the axis in which you're taking the softmax is wrong. It should be taken on the last axis.

```
pytorch_softmax = torch.nn.Softmax(-1)
```

Secondly, your `logits` consists of very large numbers. The resulting derivative of this is a very small number, hence the zeros that you are seeing.

```
tensor([[ -95782.0859,  -30961.9023,   -3614.0188,  ..., -328240.6250,
          -40818.2227, -160598.5469],
        [-182128.5938,  -76499.2969,  143654.6250,  ..., -300924.1250,
          -74291.3125, -109025.0391],
        [-163018.4062,  -71817.1172, -134466.0156,  ...,  -49884.1211,
          -19183.3691,  116674.1406],
         ...,
        [ 225013.4219,  -37008.6484,  244807.2188,  ..., -466822.8750,
           63626.5625, -147146.0781],
        [ 122045.7031,  -90937.7344,   77259.1641,  ..., -397063.9375,
         -188736.9688,  -78475.5000],
        [  23139.7578,  -14914.8359, -205065.0625,  ...,  -65808.6562,
           31458.8906,  -11362.2344]], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
```

Several things you can do to includes normalising your data, adding BatchNorm, clamping etc. I can see that your data `X` is a tensor with values ranging from 0 to 255.

Thirdly, you shouldn't need to wrap your tensors with [`nn.Parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/parameter.html) as they are only used in conjunction with the `nn.Module` class.